# VBA runs on Excel 2010 but gives an error on Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that I created on Excel 2010 but when trying to run it on Excel 2013 I get a run time 1004 error, with the debugger highlighting the line

```
 wbDest.Sheets(1).Name = cell.Value
```

I figured that anything written in 2010 would work on 2013. Was I incorrect in assuming that? Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const sColumn As String = "M"

Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngFilter As Range, rngUniques As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngFilter = Range(sColumn & "1", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With rngFilter
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
    Set rngUniques = Range(sColumn & "2", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

For Each cell In rngUniques
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value
    rngFilter.EntireRow.Copy
    With wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    wbDest.Sheets(1).Name = cell.Value
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbDest.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & cell.Value & " " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm-yy")
    wbDest.Close False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next cell

rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The code works fine for me in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this row:

```
Set rngUniques = Range(sColumn & "2", Range(sColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

to

```
Set rngUniques = Range(sColumn & "2", sColumn & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```